# Images on bxslider that has bx-clone class didnt open in lightbox

Tags: jquery, fancybox, bxslider

I have built up a slider with bxlider which images must open with lightbox.I am using fancybox.When turn came to images that has bx-clone class they didnt open in lightbox opened directly in browser.Here is my code for bxslider

```
jQuery('.inner_gallery').bxSlider({
            slideWidth: 185,
            minSlides: 2,
            maxSlides: 3,
            moveSlides: 1,
           pager : false, 
           nextSelector: '#news_gallery_slider-next-think',
             prevSelector: '#news_gallery_slider-prev-think',  
             nextText: '',
              prevText: '' ,
              onSliderLoad: function(){
                    // Event fires when you click on a clone slide
                    $('.bx-clone a').click(function(event){
                        // Prevent click event for clone slides
                       // event.preventDefault();
                        // Get the href attribute (url) of the clone slide image
                        urlOfImage = $(this).attr('href');
                        // Select the real slide by looking for a matching href attribute
                        realSlide = $(".bxslider li").not(".bx-clone").has('a[href="'+urlOfImage+'"]');
                        // Get the index of the real slide
                        realSlideIndex = $('.bxslider li').not(".bx-clone").index(realSlide);
                        // Tell magnific-popup to open the slide at the index
                        $(this).parents('.bxslider').fancybox(); 
                    });
                },
            slideMargin: 10       
          });
```

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: were you able to find a solution for this issue? if so, please share it here.

Comment: Yes sure will share!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't solved this issue with bxslider and found a good one responsive another slider with it I didnt have such problem wihh the lightbox.

I used Jcaousellite.Here is the [Jcarousellite files](https://github.com/ganeshmax/jcarousellite) you can download from here.The code is like this `jQuery(".inner_gallery").jCarouselLite({
        btnNext: "#news_gallery_slider-next-think",
        btnPrev: "#news_gallery_slider-prev-think",
        visible: 5,
        auto: 50000,
        speed: 1000
    });`

Comment: This does not solve the initial problem. It is an avoidance of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Jquery .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

This will bind events on all dom elements even if the dom elements are loaded later.

```
$('a').on('.elements_always_there', 'click', function(){
    urlOfImage = $(this).attr('href'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
display: none; /* Hidden by default */
position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%; /* Full width */
height: 100%; /* Full height */
overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
background-color: #fefefe;
margin: auto;
padding: 20px;
border: 1px solid #888;
width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
color: #aaaaaa;
float: right;
font-size: 28px;
font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
color: #000;
text-decoration: none;
cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Modal Example</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
<span class="close">&times;</span>
<p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
</div>

</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Above code is working as modal popup. in bx-slider they are using old version of Jquery lib file, in above mention code no jquery lib no needed, it will work smoothly.... if modal popup is hiding behind the slider then put inline css example:- <div class="images-slider" style="position: relative;z-index: -9">. this will work properly

Comment: Thanks, will check it out